# Reading binary from table column into byte[] array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sql-server

I'm using PBKDF2 in my application to store users passwords. In my Users table, I have a `Salt` and `Password` column which is determined like this:

```
// Hash the users password using PBKDF2
var DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_Password, 20);
byte[] _Salt = DeriveBytes.Salt;
byte[] _Key = DeriveBytes.GetBytes(20);  // _Key is put into the Password column
```

On my login page I need to retrieve this salt and password. Because they're byte[] arrays, I store them in my table as `varbinary(MAX)`. Now I need to retrieve them to compare against the users entered password. How would I do that using `SqlDataReader`? At the moment I have this:

```
cn.Open();
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Salt, Password FROM Users WHERE Email = @Email", cn);
Command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = _Email;
SqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
Reader.Read();
if (Reader.HasRows)
{
    // This user exists, check their password with the one entered
    byte[] _Salt = Reader.GetBytes(0, 0, _Salt, 0, _Salt.Length);
}
else
{
    // No user with this email exists
    Feedback.Text = "No user with this email exists, check for typos or register";
}
```

But I know for a fact that it's wrong. Other methods in `Reader` have only one parameter being the index of the column to retrieve.

Comment: How exactly do you know its wrong?  Because your doing exactly what all the other related questions are doing.  Are you sure your byte array you create can fit in `varbyte`

Comment: VS throws up an error saying it can't convert long to byte[] for one, and the parameter descriptions don't match what I put in, like `Salt._Length`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Casting it directly to a `byte[]` has worked for me so far.

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("FOO"))
{
    c.Open();
    String sql = @"
        SELECT Salt, Password 
        FROM Users 
        WHERE (Email = @Email)";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = _Email;
        using (SqlDataReader d = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (d.Read())
            {
                byte[] salt = (byte[])d["Salt"];
                byte[] pass = (byte[])d["Password"];

                //Do stuff with salt and pass
            }
            else
            {
                // NO User with email exists
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you think the code you wrote is wrong (please explain). But specifically for the error:
Notice that [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx) returns a `long` not a byte array.

So, you should use:
`Reader.GetBytes(0, 0, _Salt, 0, _Salt.Length);`

**or**
`long bytesRead = Reader.GetBytes(0, 0, _Salt, 0, _Salt.Length);`

Comment: If you look at the needed parameters for the method you can see that my parameters aren't correct, but I don't know what to specify. And I can't convert it to a long, it has to be returned as a byte array for my password checking to work.

Comment: @JamesDawson Please read the description of the GetBytes functions (which I posted in my answer): ***Reads a stream of bytes from the specified column offset into the buffer an array starting at the given buffer offset***. In other words, in your example will copy the byte stream of column number 0 into the `_Salt` variable. Which is exactly what you asked for. (The return value of the GetBytes function is only the number of bytes read and therefore it's a `long`). Did you change the code as I recommended? Did it work?